# Troubles communicating with Pathfinder DVL without TRDI Toolz

Tags: sensor, tcp-ip, underwater

Recently my team and I have acquired a Teledyne Pathfinder Doppler Velocity Log (DVL) that we are using for an AUV project. In the guide (found here: https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1447288/Teledyne-Pathfinder.html), it says to use a software called TRDI Toolz to connect and communicate with the DVL. However, we didn't get the CD containing the software, and we need to communicate with the DVL without that software anyways. Thus, I decided to connect via a PuTTY TCP terminal. However, I have had much trouble establishing communications in order to test it; simply put, I can connect to it, but I am not able to get any response from it.

To establish a connection, I kept the dvl on land and connected the power on the electronics box to a 12V, 1A power supply (1A was the limit for the supply even though the guide says it should be able to draw 2A, but that shouldn't limit its communication ability when it's not in the water, especially when it only is drawing 0.14 A, right?) The guide says that the it should be powered with 10.7-36V, so 12 volts should work for this purpose. I then connected the ethernet connector directly into my (windows 10) laptop. I launched a puTTY terminal using the ip 192.168.1.100 and Port 1033, as described in the guide. I also chose telnet as the connection type.

Once the terminal launched, I get a message on the terminal: "Connected to Pathfinder command interface". However, when I send a break (or anything really), no response occurs; I do not get a message or a '>' prompt. The LEDs inside the electronics box flashed every time I sent something, but I got no response on the terminal. I also entered the IP into my web browser to access the network configuration page as described in the guide, and when I look at the "Link Status" indicator, it says "Not Active" instead of "Active" like it does in the guide.

What am I doing wrong or missing? I don't have the TRDI toolz software, so I can't use that to connect. I could try using the serial connector, but my laptop doesn't have a matching connector for it. Does anyone who has worked with this DVL have any advice for what I can try next?

Answer (score 0):

Why not contact the vendor directly? The company has a support site and a field service staff to help out with these types of things.

- http://www.teledynemarine.com/rdi/support/
- Email: rdifs@teledyne.com
- Phone: +1-858-842-2700

They also have the [October 2018 revision of the manual](http://www.teledynemarine.com/Documents/Brand%20Support/RD%20INSTRUMENTS/Technical%20Resources/Manuals%20and%20Guides/Pathfinder/PathFinder%20DVL%20Guide_Oct18.pdf) there, which is newer than the one you mention.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I contacted them and they gave me the software, and from that I was able to determine the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. After contacting the vendor thanks to Passerby's suggestion, they sent me the TRDI Toolz software, and connecting through that helped me figure out the issue. The reason it wasn't working was that I believe puTTY sends a hard break (ctrl-C) rather than the soft break the Pathfinder needs (ctrl-S). Once I realized that, I was able to connect properly.